How to prevent Thymleaf Page rendering when doing redirect (302)?
This is my spring-boot(3.3.5)/thymeleaf application pom.xml deps:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

I have a simple controller with two Get mappings.

The page renders fine for /.
When I visit /redirect it redirects with 302 to / as expected (the browser receives the 200 response after 302). However, I notice that the 302 response also contains the rendered page of /. The browser essentially receives the same page twice.


My controller (IndexController.java):
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model){
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/redirect")
    public String redirect(Model model){
        return "redirect:/"; //302 reponse has rendered "index.html"
    }

}

Thymeleaf template (/resources/templates/index.html:
<h1>hai</h1>


How do I make the 302 redirect itself not render the page?
Why is it the default behavior?


It doesn't contain the HTML. That is only because your browser will follow the 302 (at least that is what I think). If you do the same call with a proper client like HTTPie or CURL you should see it will only include a location header.

@M.Deinum you are right! I should have checked earlier. cURL actually shows content-length: 0. You may post it as an answer.

The 302 doesn't contain the HTML. It only shows it like this as the browser will follow it.
If you would call it with something like CURL or HTTPie you will see that the 302 response only contains a Location header and no content.
